# Disk Caching/DiskLRUCache - non threaded access?

Tags: java, android, caching, disk

Every example I've seen of Jake Wharton's DiskLRUCache being used, I've seen people calling cache.get and cache.put on the main thread (ie without opening a new thread).

Is this not bad? Also, if I wanted to use a threaded call to get for a String, what's the best way to do so without creating listeners?

ie currently I have: String data = cache.get("data");

but since it's a Disk I/O operation, I'd rather move cache.get to a different thread.

Comment: From a quick glance at the code, it would seem as though making things asynchronous is your job, not the cache's. You might consider enabling `StrictMode`, though, to confirm this.